# io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.informers.impl.cache.Reflector | listSyncAndWatch failed for v1/persistentvolumes, will stop

Tags: java, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, fabric8-kubernetes-client

I am unable to sync or retrieve Kubernetes persistent volumes after a node pool is deleted and a new pool is created. I have not been able to find the root cause. Can someone please guide me in understanding the reason for this issue?

```
2023-10-30 01:56:12.135+0000 |  | ::: |    OkHttp Dispatcher |  | ERROR | io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.informers.impl.cache.Reflector | listSyncAndWatch failed for v1/persistentvolumes, will stop
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Runtime reflection is not supported for public io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.CSIPersistentVolumeSource()
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:645)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.http.StandardHttpClient.lambda$completeOrCancel$10(StandardHttpClient.java:140)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.http.ByteArrayBodyHandler.onBodyDone(ByteArrayBodyHandler.java:52)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientImpl$OkHttpAsyncBody.doConsume(OkHttpClientImpl.java:137)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Runtime reflection is not supported for public io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.CSIPersistentVolumeSource()
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:89)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor(Constructor.java:73)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:487)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor.call(AnnotatedConstructor.java:123)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createUsingDefault(StdValueInstantiator.java:278)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:303)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.model.jackson.SettableBeanPropertyDelegate.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanPropertyDelegate.java:134)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.model.jackson.SettableBeanPropertyDelegate.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanPropertyDelegate.java:134)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:359)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.model.jackson.SettableBeanPropertyDelegate.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanPropertyDelegate.java:134)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2105)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1481)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.KubernetesSerialization.unmarshal(KubernetesSerialization.java:254)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.lambda$handleResponse$0(OperationSupport.java:562)
        at java.base@11.0.19/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
        ... 18 more
```

Comment: It was a native image tracing issue. After running the NI tracing, it's working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a native image tracing issue. After running the NI tracing, it's working again.